# Importing an nummeric cell with excel

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to import in excel file in to my database. I have my code here. The code can only import text, but I want to import "INT" also. I have changed `pst.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());` to `pst.setInt(1, row.getCell(0).getIntCellValue());`, but that didnt work out either.

```
   @FXML
private void importExcel(){
    try {
        conn = Database.connectdb();
        String query = "Insert into registratie(naam, lostandfoundID, kenmerken, labelnummer, luchthaven) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        String excelFilePath = "Bagage.xlsx";
        try (FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fileIn)) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                pst.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
                pst.setInt(2, row.getCell(1).getCellType());
                pst.setString(3, row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                pst.setInt(4, row.getCell(3).getCellType());
                pst.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
                pst.execute();
            }            

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("BagageOverzicht");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Data succesvol geïmporteerd!");
            alert.showAndWait();

        }
        pst.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BagageOverzichtController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BagageOverzichtController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific, what is the problem? Is the code compiling?

Comment: Add tags `apache-poi` and `jdbc` to your question.

Comment: divide problem and resolve. 1. get from excell into variable 2. write into db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited:

Use the for loop as mentioned below-

```
for(int i=1; i<=sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){
    try{
        row = sheet.getRow(i);
        pst.setString(1, row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
        pst.setInt(2, row.getCell(1).getNumericCellValue());
        pst.setString(3, row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
        pst.setInt(4, row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue());
        pst.setString(5, row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue());
        pst.execute();
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Then you can try-


pst.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(row.getCell(1).toString()))

Comment: Edited my answer. Kindly check for the same. I am currently using this in my code.

Comment: For date and time, try using-

`row.getCell(0).getDateCellValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Try just to get string value and then parse that as int just writing `Integer.parseInt(yourStringValue);`

Answer (score 0):

Getting Cell Value: Always use right type getter ([`getStringCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getStringCellValue--), [`getNumericCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getNumericCellValue--), ...) for a cell. Use [`getCellType()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCell.html#getCellType--) method for determining the cell type because sometimes numbers are stored in text cells.

Setting DB Value: Always use right type setter ([`setString(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString-int-java.lang.String-), [`setLong(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setLong-int-long-), ...) according to database column type.

Use type conversion if Java types for getters and setters mismatch.

This way you should succeed.